# Fill input field in Elementor pop-up

Tags: javascript, elementor

I am trying to create a function which would fill input in popup window automatically depending on brn id that was clicked.

This is where I am at:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.popup-activator')
let btnId

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   btnId = this.id;
});
document.getElementById("form-field-id").value = btnId;
```

I can see that my id is saved in btnId, but it's not showing up in form field. It might be because when I click the button popup is not generated on the page yet, it opens after I click the button.
Here is the link I am trying to do this https://www.avistech.cz/pujcovna-nakladace/ it's applied on first button 'Poptat'

If can anyone help I would really appriciate it

Comment: where do you want the btnId to reflect ?

Comment: In the popup, which shows after I click the button 'Poptat'. In the input field named Obj.č. it has ID I use in code #form-field-id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the value to the input, when the modal is fully loaded.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-activator')

btns.forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const btnId = this.id;
    // setting the value inside the fn so that it triggers after the button clicks
    // setTimeout delays the assignment a little so that the modal gets mounted
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("form-field-id").value = btnId;
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: I actually have another problem. This code works just for first button, but not for the other ones. Do you think that its because of document.querySelector('.popup-activator')? It might be too general to work with multiple buttons.

Comment: You need to use `querySelectorAll` and then use a `for loop`. Let me update the code.

Comment: I would like to have another question. This solution works fine on desktop, but it doesn't on mobile devices. It also doesnt work in anonymous mode.  Do you have any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: The reason that it is not working on the mobile is maybe the change of the classes and id.  Usually, in platforms like elementor, Squarespace, etc the classes get changed on smaller screen size. Please check that once. if that is the case then apply the code for those classes.